# How to define IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS for MSIPackage in Wix Bundle

Tags: c#, wix

Could you please help me a bit, how to define the IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS command-line parameter in my Wix bundle to use when install the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Localdb.

I got an error during installing that IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS command-line parameter is missing.

I call the SQLLocalDb.msi with the following command:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)Prerequisites\SqlLocalDB.msi" Compressed="yes" />
```

But I am not able to define a InstallCommand like in case of ExePackage

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to a  `MsiProperty` inside the `MsiPackage` with the name `IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS` and the value `YES`:

```
<!-- Sql server Installation --> 
   <PackageGroup Id="SqlLocalDB2014Installation" > 
      <MsiPackage SourceFile=".\Prerequisites\SqlLocalDB2014.MSI" Compressed="yes" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" Vital="yes" 
              InstallCondition="NOT(SQLSERVERDB2014_EXIST)"> 
    <MsiProperty Name="IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS" Value="YES"/> 
  </MsiPackage> 
</PackageGroup>
```

Regarding the check for an existing installation, you indeed need to check the registry. I have included an example below, although the `key` will be dependent on the exact version (32 vs 64 bit, standard vs express, etc). See this [blog](http://robs-got-a-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/detecting-sql-server-from-wix-installer.html) for further details.

```
<property id="SQLSERVERDB2014_EXIST">
<registrysearch id="SQLServer2005orLater"
   key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
   name="MSSQL"
   root="HKLM"
   type="raw"
   win64="no">
</registrysearch>
</property>
```

Comment: SQLSERVERDB2012_EXIST is a predefined condition, or should I set it according to something?

Comment: You can ignore that bit, you just need to add the `MsiProperty`

Comment: Ok, I understand, but If i would like to check that the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Localdb has already installed, then should i check it in the registry, or there is a predefined condition like the NETFRAMEWORK45 in case of the .Net framework?

Comment: Yes, you need to check the registry, added an example for this